# Postgres upsert (update and insert ) from another table successfully,but id value getting duplicated for one value

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to UPSERT DATA from one table to another table.There are some duplicate value in them.Fist table look like this,table-a:

```
 id | deviceserial | time_difference
----+--------------+-----------------
  1 | 636363636891 |               3
  2 | 636363636890 |             123
  3 | 6625839827   |              29
  4 | 6625839832   |              60
  5 | 6625839830   |             120
  6 | 6625839828   |               4
  7 | 6625839833   |              60
```

```
Another table name table-b:
id | deviceserial | time_difference
----+--------------+-----------------
  1 | 636363636891 |               3
  2 | 636363636890 |             123
  3 | 6625839835   |              60
  4 | 6625839827   |              29
  5 | 6625839832   |              60
  6 | 6625839830   |             120
  7 | 6625839828   |               4
  8 | 6625839833   |              60
```

I am trying UPSERT from table-b to table-a with this query bellow:

```
INSERT INTO table-a (id,deviceSerial,time_difference) SELECT id,deviceSerial,time_difference FROM table-b ON CONFLICT (deviceserial) DO  UPDATE SET time_difference=device_usage1.time_difference + excluded.time_difference;
```

I am getting this this result.

```
id | deviceserial | time_difference
----+--------------+-----------------
  1 | 636363636891 |               6
  2 | 636363636890 |             246
  3 | 6625839835   |              60
  3 | 6625839827   |              58
  4 | 6625839832   |             120
  5 | 6625839830   |             240
  6 | 6625839828   |               8
  7 | 6625839833   |             120
```

Its updating and inserting successfully .But one id  is duplicated(non duplicated deviceSerial ).What can be the reason?

Comment: MySQL or Postgresql? Please tag the only the relevant database.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy ,Its Postgresql and edited .

Comment: Why shouldn't the `id` be duplicated? According to the query, you're only preventing duplicated `deviceserial`s.

Comment: @xehpuk you are right .But,If I put id and deviceSerial both not to be duplicated in query give me wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

Try excluding `id` from your `SELECT`. Assuming `id` is an auto-incremented value in `table-a`, a new unique ID will be generated when you insert new values.

```sql
INSERT INTO table-a (id,deviceSerial,time_difference)
SELECT deviceSerial,time_difference FROM table-b 
ON CONFLICT (deviceserial) DO 
UPDATE SET time_difference=device_usage1.time_difference + excluded.time_difference;
```

I strongly recommend adding a constraint to `id` if you want to enforce uniqueness. It looks like the primary key of the table. You could also drop `id` completely and just use `deviceSerial` as the primary key, as it seems that value must be unique as well.