# Postgres Upsert with Select

Tags: postgresql, subquery, upsert

I'm trying to upsert a record with a select:

```
INSERT INTO global_search (entity_id, entity_type, search_content)
SELECT id, 'user', "username"
FROM "user"
WHERE "id" = 1
ON CONFLICT (entity_id) DO UPDATE
SET search_content = excluded.username
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  column excluded.username does not exist
LINE 8: SET search_content = excluded.username
```

This seems like it should work per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393914/postgres-upsert-update-and-insert-from-another-table-successfully-but-id-valu). If I remove the ON CONFLICT bit it works fine. Normal upserts with values lists work fine as well.

I'm running postgresql 13.4.

Comment: Are you trying to bulk change rows?  Probably it worth checking the new MERGE feature on PostgresSQL >= v15


It would be something like:
 MERGE INTO s1 USING s2 ON id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ....  WHEN NO MATCHED THEN INSERT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `EXCLUDED.search_content`. The column name is that of the target column in the table into which you `INSERT`.